# when scroll not finished don't again scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can prevent to do again scroll event in jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() ){
           console.log('scroll');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`

Comment: Your `console.log()` never appears to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You should catch the event, using it in scroll function as a param. And do, event.preventDefault() or event.stopPropagation()